# Jackson ObjectMapper configuration - error JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('b' (code 98)):

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have generated JSON in the following format

```
[{"empNo":"2390","empName":"JAMES","projects":{"projectId":209,"projectName":"Z560"}}]
```

How do I configure ObjectMapper for the above?

I have declared ObjectMapper as

```
private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
static {
    om.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
    om.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
    om.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, 
                 true);
    om.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, 
                 false);
    om.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion
   (JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
   }
```

However I am still getting the following error

> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
>       SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not
>       be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
>       org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('b' (code 98)): 
>       expected a valid value (number, String, array, object,
>       'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1fef0b44; line: 1,
>       column: 2]

Expected output is

```
{"empNo":"2390","empName":"JAMES","projectId":"209","projectName":"Z560"}
```

Comment: Uh, your original JSON is valid, why do you want to alter it at all?

Comment: @fge Client is not expecting the generated JSON. Thanks

Comment: And in what way doesn't it expect the generated JSON?

Comment: @fge Expected output `{"empNo":"2390","empName":"JAMES","projectId":"209","projectName":"Z560"}`

Comment: @Polppan can't you convert this json to Map and then parse to get the desired the json.

Comment: @ankur-singhal How could I do this?

Comment: So, what you want to do is basically real ALL numeric values as strings, right? Not sure why but this looks like a XY problem to me... So why don't you step back and describe the problem? And by "problem" I  mean how the JSON you get is not what you want. For some reasons I surmise this has nothing to do with Strings at all...

Comment: @Polppan done, have a look, the `function getMap()` can be shorten if you have fix json instead of making it generalised

Comment: @ankur-singhal I will have a look. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A bit lengthy, can be optimized. refer [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/11/json-to-hashmap-parsing-json-string.html) for more.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String originalJson = "{\"empNo\":\"2390\",\"empName\":\"JAMES\",\"projects\":{\"projectId\":209,\"projectName\":\"Z560\"}}";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(originalJson);
            Map<String, Object> map = getMap(jsonObject);
            System.out.println("My Old Map => " + map);

            Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().equals("projects")) {
                    Map<String, Object> projectMap = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry1 : projectMap.entrySet()) {
                        newMap.put(entry1.getKey(), entry1.getValue());
                    }
                } else {
                    newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
                }
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(newMap);
            System.out.println("My New Map => " + newMap);
            System.out.println("Expected Json String => " + jsonObject1.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Map getMap(JSONObject object) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Object jsonObject = null;
        String key = null;
        Object value = null;

        try {
            Iterator<String> keys = object.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {

                key = null;
                value = null;

                key = keys.next();

                if (null != key && !object.isNull(key)) {
                    value = object.get(key);
                }

                if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                    map.put(key, getMap((JSONObject) value));
                    continue;
                }

                if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray array = ((JSONArray) value);
                    List list = new ArrayList();
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++) {
                        jsonObject = array.get(i);
                        if (jsonObject instanceof JSONObject) {
                            list.add(getMap((JSONObject) jsonObject));
                        } else {
                            list.add(jsonObject);
                        }
                    }
                    map.put(key, list);
                    continue;
                }

                map.put(key, value);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return map;
    }
```

**Output**

> My Old Map => {projects={projectId=209, projectName=Z560},
>   empName=JAMES, empNo=2390}
>
> My New Map => {empName=JAMES, empNo=2390, projectId=209,
>   projectName=Z560}
>
> Expected Json String =>
>   {"empName":"JAMES","empNo":"2390","projectId":209,"projectName":"Z560"}

Comment: OP uses Jackson, not org.json!

Comment: My generated JSON start with `[` and ends with `]`. Can ObjectMapper can configure this?

Comment: @Polppan i think you can remove these brackets, it will not accept with the `[` or `]`

Comment: @ankur-singhal I have this exception while running `org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )` Not sure where to put configuration as ObectMapper is not used in your example though.

Comment: @Polppan it is not required `configuration`

Comment: @ankur-singhal Due to above exception, json is not generated.